# Comma-separated arrays using map() and get()

Tags: jquery

I'm outputting two separate raw Javascript arrays to two separate divs. One is being displayed with elements being comma-separated, and the other is not. Can anyone explain the difference between what's going on here? Why is one result being outputted with commas?

Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ahgcue4w/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = [$('li').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get()];
    $('#results1').html(a);

    var b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
    $('#results2').html(b);
});


<ul>
    <li>Chicago</li>
    <li>Seattle</li>
    <li>San Diego</li>
    <li>Austin</li>
    <li>Denver</li>
</ul>

<div id="results1"></div>
<br />
<div id="results2"></div>
```

Comment: What you're passing the array to jQuery's "html" method, the array toString method is called.

Comment: `.get()` returns an array which you are putting inside another array by wrapping the whole thing in `[]`. `a` is an array within an array, `b` is just an array. https://jsfiddle.net/ahgcue4w/3/

Comment: @George got it. That's the right answer. I was passing an array within an array. I removed the wrapping brackets [] and it is not being comma-separated now. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @George's solution happens to be the same as the one in my answer, which i posted a couple minutes after. Would you be willing to accept it, as otherwise this question will be left "hanging" (no upvoted or accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.html()`, when passed an array, automatically joins the items with no separator (i.e. a separator of an empty string). Therefore, for B, you get `ABCDE` all together. With A though, you have a nested array. You map and get an array, then stick that inside another array (`[$().get()]`). When jQuery combines items of this array, there's only one: the inner array. JavaScript then joins this inner array using `.toString()`, which places commas between the items. Therefore, you get a comma-separated array.

Compare:

```js
document.writeln('Single nesting:');
document.writeln(['A','B','C','D','E'].join(''));
document.writeln('Double nesting:');
document.writeln([['A','B','C','D','E']].join(''));
// still waiting for a snippet console...
// http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/259693
```

Answer (score -2):

When you're passing the array to jQuery's "html" method, the Array.prototype.toString method is called.

Give it a try:

```
["123", "anc"].toString()
```

You can control this default behaviour by using "join", and specifying the desired separator.

```
// Join all element by a white-space
["123", "anc"].join(" ") // --> "123 anc"

// Join all element by a dash
["123", "anc"].join("-") // --> "123-anc"
```